# "error: expected expression" when compiling from command line but not from Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, clang++

I compiled the following code snippet with `clang++` (700.1.76) and Xcode 7.1 separately.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(int x1 = 0, int y1 = 0) {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
    string display() {
        return "(" + to_string(x) + ", " + to_string(y) + ")";
    }
};

class Shape {
private:
    Point bottomLeft;
    Point upperRight;
public:
    Shape(Point bottomLeft1, Point upperRight1) {
        bottomLeft = bottomLeft1;
        upperRight = upperRight1;
    }
    Point getBottomLeft() {
        return bottomLeft;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Point p1(1, 2);
    Point p2(3, 4);
    Shape s1(p1, p2);
    Shape s2({1, 2}, {3, 4});
    cout << s1.getBottomLeft().display() << endl;
    cout << s2.getBottomLeft().display() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In Xcode, I get the expected output of

```
(2, 1)
(2, 1)
```

but using `clang++`, the program fails to compile and throw this error:

```
test.cpp:38:11: error: expected expression
    Shape s2({1, 2}, {3, 4});
             ^
```

(This same error is repeated for the `{3, 4}` thing as well.)

What's going on here?

Comment: It could be an issue with your version of clang.  It compiles [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4e80aad57256b57)

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm, compiling with my `clang` using those flags works, but without them it doesn't. Actually, compiling with `-std=c++14` as the only flag works, but not specifying `-std` causes errors. I'm guessing, then, that it's important to specify the language standard?

Comment: Yes for this to work you need to have at least `std=c++11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to specify the language standard when calling `clang++`.

Apparently, anything above `c++11` will do.